# How to order by random() in ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite, query-builder

How to make a query to get random() rows with limit of 3 rows?

I tried but get error:

```
myQueryBuilder.orderBy("random()", true);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it by using the [`orderByRaw(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#orderByRaw%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
myQueryBuilder.orderByRaw("RANDOM()");
```